# Explain the Halls Condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[From this PDF](http://myweb.facstaff.wwu.edu/sarkara/hall.pdf):

> [image]

I don't really understand the definition of Hall's theorem.

Can someone provide another explanation for it?

Comment: I assume you mean you don't understand the *statement* of Hall's *condition*? And this is a rather broad request. What is it that you don't understand - the terminology? The proof? Please provide more information.

Comment: The theorem it self. the way it has been stated

Answer (score 1):

You've got a (finite) set, $V_1$. You've got a (finite) set, $V_2$. You've got lines going from elements of $V_1$ to elements of $V_2$. You want to know whether you can pick a bunch of these lines so they involve every element of $V_1$, and don't involve any element of $V_2$ more than once. That's called a complete matching.

Hall says, take a subset, $S$, of $V_1$, look at all the lines joining elements of $S$ to elements of $V_2$, and count how many elements of $V_2$ are involved in those lines. Then there's a complete matching if and only if the number of elements of $V_2$ involved in the lines from $S$ is at least as big as the number of elements of $S$, for all possible subsets $S$ of $V_1$.

OK?